# Can't migrate table with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, migrate

When I try to migrate this:

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :category
      t.string :text
      t.string :asset_name
      t.string :correct_answers, array:true, default: []
      t.string :wrong_answers, array:true, default: []
      t.integer :score

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I get error:

> == 20161217135738 CreateTasks: migrating ======================================
>   -- create_table(:tasks) rails aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> can't quote Array

I am using rails 5 and mysql on development.
Any idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: postgresql database

Comment: @edit sorry, i forgot its development evn, I am using mysql

Comment: Then there is your answer :) You could use `Serialize` with mysql. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html So generate the correct and wrong answers as strings. Inside the Task model put serialize :correct_answers, Array. Same for the wrong_answers.

Comment: I can't create arrray in mysql db?

Comment: No idea why I can't edit my comments here.

Comment: So it would be "t.string serialize :correct_answers, array:true, default: []" ?

Comment: No, `t.string :correct_answers` and `t.string :wrong_answers`. Then inside the Task model put both attributes as `serialize :correct_answers, Array` and `serialize :wrong_answers, Array`.

Comment: Alright, but isn't that considered bad practice when I am using postgres in production?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using mysql instead of postgres in development?

Comment: Maybe I should use postgres on development instead of mysql as well?

Comment: I would do that, yes.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you absolutely should use PostgreSQL in dev if that's what you're deploying on. There are so many differences between databases (data types, keywords, quoting rules, GROUP BY behavior, date/time functions, case sensitivity of LIKE, regex support, ...) that using different databases in dev, test, and production is madness and about as much fun as bobbing for apples in a bucket of fish hooks.

Comment: If my information was helpful then mark my answer as correct

Answer (score -1):

If you want support all databases you must serialize the array in a String I am giving you an example

```
class Documents < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :share
end

class AddShareToDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   add_column :documents, :share, :string, :default => []
 end 
end
```